# Sharing Controls from multiple forms/classes

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm currently stuck in how to share controls between two forms. 
This is what i want to do: 
- I have several forms that have their own function.
- Now i want to bring them all to gather on one mainform.

Normally i do this by creating the following code:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim f As New Form2
    GroupBox1.Controls.Add(f.Get_Groupbox_controls)
End Sub
End Class
```

This add all the control containing in Form2.Groupbox1 and adds it to Form1.Groupbox1. 
Normally this works just fine for me.

Where "Get_Groupbox_controls" is a function that returns Form2.Groupbox1

Or if this doesn't works i display the entire form2 over form1 with a transparancykey. (this isn't a need solution, you have to do a lot of location calculating,  but it works)

However now i got a form that has a lot going on. For the mainform i only want to display one Container(groupbox) but when the user clicks "More setting.." then it has to show the entire form with all the control on it.

The problem is when i use the container.controls.add() function i get an exception        "Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created "
The Error is logical because the entire form isn't made yet. But in order for the form to work properly it has to update the "hidden" UI controls (labels/buttons/etc)

So the main question is, how can i "port" a selection of controls from Form1 to form2 and keep all the handlers etc.. on Form1

Answer (score 2):

If you have two forms where you want to place identical looking/functioning GroupBox sections, you may want to consider creating a custom user control that contains the shared functionality and can be placed in each form.  User controls can even be added to a form through the form designer in Visual Studio.

Comment: Hi Scott, Thanks for your reply. i'd looked in to this but i thought it wouldn't fit in my solution because i make the buttons(controls) in a groupbox runtime on form2, and it has to connected with a Serialport that is also opened on form2. So i'm not sure how i can use a user control with only one Serialport connection? (or it has to be a different "SerialPort" class that gets and sets data between the class and user control? but then it would be difficult to update the controls on SerialDataReceived event.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that these controls were dynamically added to form2 at runtime.  The problem you're going to face is that a control cannot be shared by two forms.  This has to do with the fact that a Control can only have a single parent which you can access through the Parent property.  Simply using the Add method for one form's ControlCollection will remove the existing Parent of the control and make the new form the Parent.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, missed that part in my knowledge ;-) I got it to work, but in a different situation. I made a panel with all the controls on in, FormA add all the controls of FormB in a panel, and then we resize the panel to show/hide the controls, everything works great! :-)  Thanks for the help!